# Sylius, SearchBundle

Tags: symfony, search, doctrine, sylius

Search in latest Sylius-standard does not work:

[Syntax Error] line 0, col 92: Error: Expected known function, got 'MATCH'

[1/2] QueryException: select u.itemId, u.tags, u.entity from Sylius\Bundle\SearchBundle\Model\SearchIndex u WHERE MATCH(u.value) AGAINST (:searchTerm) > 0

How to fix?

Comment: You should add a sample of your code to show how you're trying to do the search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the custom function to you doctrine config as in the Sylius [app/config/config.yml](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/app/config/config.yml#L66-L68)

```
doctrine:
    ...
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                MATCH:  Sylius\Bundle\SearchBundle\Extension\Doctrine\MatchAgainstFunction
```

Comment: After this: doctrine:    ...
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                MATCH:  Sylius\Bundle\SearchBundle\Extension\Doctrine\MatchAgainstFunction I have: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException' with message 'Unrecognized option "dql" under "doctrine.orm"' in sylius\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ArrayNode.php:316

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Unrecognized option "dql" under "doctrine.orm"'

Comment: Can you provide a link to a demo version of the store with a working Sylius search?

Comment: I don't know if there is one, I haven't made one anyway.  Your error is due to the fact that `MATCH` isn't a part of the base Doctrine system so you need to add the custom functions. `doctrine.orm.dql` is a shortcut to `doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default.dql` so addng it there may work (like in the master version of Sylius - https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/app/config/config.yml#L42-L68)

Comment: Can you provide a link to a demo version of the store with a working Sylius search?

Comment: **I don't know if there is one, I haven't made one anyway.**

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to get it working :

1. In app/config/config.yml put in the following lines

```html
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %sylius.database.driver%
        host:     %sylius.database.host%
        port:     %sylius.database.port%
        dbname:   %sylius.database.name%
        user:     %sylius.database.user%
        password: %sylius.database.password%
        charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    gedmo_loggable:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
                        is_bundle: false
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true
                dql:
                    string_functions:
                        MATCH: Sylius\Bundle\SearchBundle\Extension\Doctrine\MatchAgainstFunction
```

2. In your mysql database look for the table sylius_search_index and check if it has a full index on the value column, if not just run the below command :

   ALTER TABLE `sylius_search_index` ADD FULLTEXT index_name(
   value
   )
3. On the console run the following command for your products:

   php app/console sylius:search:index

The above command builds a list of search terms for the search in the sylius_search_index table value column.

That should be all !

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, the search still does not work. After trying to run the command  php app/console sylius:search:index I have: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product::get0() in sylius\sylius-standard\vendor\s
ylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\SearchBundle\Indexer\OrmIndexer.php on line 245

Comment: Has to be something related to your setup. I'm using sylius standard and no such error. Check if the table sylius_search_index exists in your database and is of type MYISAM.

Comment: The table sylius_search_index exists in my database and is of type MYISAM:  http://clip2net.com/s/3c0BBjO

Comment: Can you provide a link to a demo version of the store with a working Sylius search?

Comment: The current demo of the sylius website has the search but its not working at the moment at demo.sylius.org. You can put an issue request on gitHub to have the owner fix the problems on the demo website.